# Variable always evaluates to false

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements, velocity.js

I'm learning jQuery and I'm just testing how events and conditions works. I'm also using Velocity.js for animating. Here is the code:

```
$(function() {

$( "#navBar" ).click(function() {
    var isOpen = false;
      if (isOpen == false){
       $( this ).velocity({ height: 300});
          isOpen = true;
          console.log(isOpen);
          return false;
      }
      else{
       $( this ).velocity({ height: 50});
          isOpen = false;
          console.log(isOpen);
      }

   });

});
```

I don't know why this isn't working. The *if condition* get executed and log to the console the variable is true. But after a second click keeps running the if condition and returning isOpen true. I can't execute the else statement.

Comment: `isOpen` will *always* be false. You need to declare it outside of the click function.

Comment: Kepp the isOpn outside the button click and add the isOpen = true inside if block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare `isOpen` outside click handler, as having it inside the handler will make it `false` always.

```
var isOpen = false;

$( "#navBar" ).click(function() {

      if (isOpen == false){
       $( this ).velocity({ height: 300});
          isOpen = true;
          console.log(isOpen);
          return false;
      }
      else{
       $( this ).velocity({ height: 50});
          isOpen = false;
          console.log(isOpen);
      }

   });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Because everytime `isOpen = false;` since you are declaring it inside `click`. So just keep it outside `click event` as below:

```
$(function() {
   var isOpen = false; //this here
   $( "#navBar" ).click(function() {
      if (isOpen == false){
          $( this ).velocity({ height: 300});
          isOpen = true;
          console.log(isOpen);
          return false;
      }
      else{
          $( this ).velocity({ height: 50});
          isOpen = false;
          console.log(isOpen);
      }
   });
});
```